# Invert trackpad/mouse events in Cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, quartz-graphics

I would like to invert the trackpad or mouse movements so sliding up would go down on the screen and sliding down would go up (this is just general cursor movements not gestures). I have gotten this to work using eventtaps and CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint() but the result is too gitery (since both events are handled). Does anyone know an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother trying to modify the events themselves - just interpret the received coordinates differently, by multiplying the Y coordinate you get in `mouseMoved:` by -1.

Comment: Thanks, but I want this to be system wide not just within the app - can you do this with mouseMoved: - I was under the impression that you could not.

Comment: No, you can't - but you didn't make that requirement clear in your question. I was thinking you were writing a flight sim or similar, where moving the mouse up would pitch the plan down.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t reinvent [the wheel](https://github.com/correia/Scrollvetica).

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I want. I want the mouse cursor to move but not the gesture scrolling.